# CAML query - filter optional

Tags: xml, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to run a CAML query with filter. I have scenario where a filter value can be null but then it does not return any record. I would like Business Area to be optional (if possible). For example, I have a country where business area is blank and query should return 1 record.

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Limit' />
            <Value Type='Number'>5000</Value>
         </Eq>
         <And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Country' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>Argentina</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='BusinessArea' />
               <Value Type='Lookup'>Sales</Value>
            </Eq>
         </And>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an OR to the CAML. The following CAML works

```
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Limit' />
        <Value Type='Number'>5000</Value>
      </Eq>
      <And>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='Country' />
          <Value Type='Choice'>South Africa</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Or>
          <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='BusinessArea' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'></Value>
          </Eq>
          <IsNull>
            <FieldRef Name='BusinessArea' />
          </IsNull>
        </Or>
      </And>
    </And>
  </Where>
```